# Установленный nginx не проходит проверку при помощи nginx -t?

Tags: nginx

1. Установил `nginx` командой `sudo apt-get install nginx`
2. До этого установлен `NodeJs` (не думаю что он влияет на проблему)
3. Так же установлены `mysql`, `php`.
   Всё выше указанное устанавливалось по [инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-ubuntu-16-04-ru)

И сразу запускаю проверку при помощи команды `nginx -t` и получаю warning:

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
>   2019/01/09 13:39:22 [warn] 14452#14452: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
>   nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>   2019/01/09 13:39:22 [emerg] 14452#14452: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

*Но запись ошибки производится! Почему тогда он выдаёт alert?*

Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то не создалась папка `site-avalible`, а файл `default.conf` (расположен в папке `conf.d`) имеет вид:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

содержание `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите список подключенных репозиториев, что-то я на них подозреваю

Comment: @andreymal а как их посмотреть?

Comment: Кроме того, не забываете ли вы запускать `nginx -t` от рута?

Comment: в файлах и каталогах /etc/apt/sources-чтототам

Comment: так файлы все рутовые, может нужно `sudo nginx -t`?

Comment: @andreymal да в этом проблема была. А почему не создаются папки `sites-available` и `sites-enabled?

Comment: @doox911 потому что покажите список репозиториев, а дальше уже посмотрим

Comment: @andreymal этот файл - sources.list?

Comment: @doox911 и содержимое каталога sources.list.d тоже (если там что-то есть). Прикрепите к тексту вопроса

Comment: Ну да, `http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/` это сторонний репозиторий со сторонним nginx. (Точнее, он напрямую от разработчика nginx и в этом смысле не сторонний, но для дебиана/убунты он всё же сторонний.) У него другая структура каталогов и в нём нету этих самых sites-available. Кроме того, если я правильно помню, этот сторонний nginx работает не в пользователе `www-data` (как стандартный), а в `nginx`, что тоже может привести к возне с правами доступа в будущем

Comment: @andreymal Что такое `www-data`? И какой источник указать?

Comment: @doox911 как можно было понять из моего предыдущего комментария, www-data это такой пользователь

Comment: Если вам не хочется возиться и хочется стандартный nginx со стандартными каталогами, предлагаю удалить всё подчистую (`apt-get purge nginx` и удалить каталог /etc/nginx если там что-то есть), удалить этот сторонний репозиторий и установить nginx заново уже из стандартных репозиториев (не забыв перед этим apt-get update, разумеется)

Comment: @andreymal какой источник указать?

Comment: @doox911 никакой, все остальные репозитории стандатрные и содержат стандартный nginx

Comment: @andreymal сделал. Нет таких папок. Только теперь папка `modules` добавилась.

Comment: Не верю, опишите полную последовательность, что вы сделали

Comment: @andreymal как вас в чат пригласить?

Comment: @doox911 сейчас сам появлюсь